# Log in module on 403 page

Tags: authentication, joomla, footer

I have a website for family content. I wanted to block external users so I set the pages to be visible just for registered users. So I put a login module to the footer so that users (me and my family members can log in even if the error page came up that you are not allowed to view this page (before logging in). It worked well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5ckw.png)

However, after I upgraded to Joomla 3.10 the error page appears differently and my footer with the login module is not visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRkEW.png)

Unfortunately, I haven't made a backup for a long time so using an earlier version of the site is not an option. Could you help me find a good solution to this problem? Creating another method to log in or customize the error page or whatever good idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying you are not able to login as an administrator, or just as a registered user? If you can log in as an administrator, I would disable the module, and check the view permissions that it has.

Comment: @Imre I see that you have not yet joined [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- please do.  After doing so, if you'd like this page to be moved to JSE, I can help with that.  Leave me a comment authorizing the migration and I'll get in contact with Stack Overflow moderators.

Comment: @James: It is the log ín module itself that doesn't appear so noone can log ín.

Comment: You don't need a module to login as an administrator, just navigate to admin side.  http://csaladfalva.hu/administrator/

Comment: It isn't me who need login option but my family members. I just don't want our family contents to be public to the world just for my family.